# Durable functions - call activity within activity

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

In durable function , we can chain activities in the orchestrator. Is it possible to call an activity within an activity. For instance, activity1 is doing some business logic and I want to pass that input to activity2. These inputs are created in a loop, hence to achieve maximum performance, it would be better if one can trigger activity2 as and when inputs are created in activity1. Is it possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported.

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/157

> We don't support calling activity functions outside of the orchestration context. It is an interesting idea, so I opened a separate issue to track the idea: [#160](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/160)

As you mentioned, the only supported way in achieving this is [function chaining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=python#chaining).

Comment: Orchestrators can call [Sub-Orchestrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sub-orchestrations) if you’re looking to nest blocks of logic.